# How do you get the lastest record from a row in SQL within ASP

Tags: sql, asp-classic

So this has been driving me crazy. I'm using the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM
    CensusFacility_Records
WHERE
    Division_Program ='Division 1'
ORDER by JMS_UpdateDateTime DESC
```

I'm trying to get the latest record. Keep in mind that there are multiple rows with "Division 1" within the Division_Program field. I just need to get the latest record from today that contains 'Division 1'.

JMS_UpdateDateTime field is populated with a timestamp using the month, day, year and time format (i.e. 8/23/2013 8:00:05 AM)

How can I get the latest record from today?'

I'm Updating my question. I'm trying to write to write to the latest record in a table.

When I look at the table the latest record is not updated

```
<%  
divrec = request.QueryString("div")
Set rstest = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rstest.locktype = adLockOptimistic
sql = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM CensusFacility_Records WHERE Division_Program ='Division 1' ORDER BY JMS_UpdateDateTime DESC"
rstest.Open sql, db
%>

<%
Shipment_Current = request.form("Shipment_Current")
Closed_Bed_Current = request.form("Closed_Bed_Current")
Available_Current = request.form("Available_Current")

rstest.fields("Shipment") = Shipment_Current
rstest.fields("Closed_Bed") = Closed_Bed_Current
rstest.fields("Current") = Available_Current
rstest.update
Response.Redirect("chooseScreen.asp")

%>
```

Comment: I updated my answer below. Let me know if this works for you! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of what I understand, the `TOP` keyword is what you are looking for. Would you mind specifying what version of MSSQL server you are querying against? This solution only works considering your data is stored in a valid dating format (like timestamp), if your data is stored in a text format you only require to convert it before sorting against it.

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM
    CensusFacility_Records
WHERE
    Division_Program ='Division 1'
ORDER BY
    JMS_UpdateDateTime DESC
```

If you have any questions feel free to comment! :-)

---

**EDIT**

Ok, now it's an ASP question! I've never done classic ASP, but inspired by a few minutes of tutorial I would recommend using this approach :

1. Grab the primary key of the object you got from your SQL select
2. Construct the following update query
3. Execute the update query

the query

```
UPDATE CensusFacility_Records SET
    Shipment = @Shipment_Current,
    Closed_Bed = @Closed_Bed_Current,
    Current = @AvailableCurrent
WHERE CensusFacility_Records.ID = @ID
```

with an ASP script that is probably going to ressemble this :

```
sql = "UPDATE CensusFacility_Records SET "
sql = sql & "Shipment ='" & Request.Form("Shipment_Current") & "'," &
sql = sql & "Closed_Bed ='" & Request.Form("Closed_Bed_Current") & "'," &
sql = sql & "Current ='" & Request.Form("AvailableCurrent") &
sql = sql & "WHERE CensusFacility_Records.ID = " & ID
conn.Execute sql
conn.close
```

Comment: It's good but I'm trying to write to a record. I've update my question

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know if this works for you; as I've never done ASP I'm not sure if it's exactly correct, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the same query you doing but add Select Top 1

```
"SELECT TOP 1 * FROM CensusFacility_Records WHERE Division_Program ='Division 1' ORDER by JMS_UpdateDateTime desc "
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub-query to find the last dattimestamp and then join to that sub-query. Also, please don't use `SELECT *` in real life.

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    CensusFacility_Records CR1
INNER JOIN
        (SELECT CR2.Division_Program
                ,Max(CR2.JMS_UpdateDateTime) as LAST_DATE
        FROM    CensusFacility_Records CR2
        GROUP BY
                CR2.Division_Program
        ) SQ
ON      SQ.Division_Program =  CR1.Division_Program
AND     SQ.LAST_DATE = CR1.JMS_UpdateDateTime
WHERE   CR1.Division_Program ='Division 1'
```

Comment: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers

 error '8000ffff' 

Query cannot be updated because the FROM clause is not a single simple table name.

Comment: I bet you trying to open the recordset for Write access

Comment: Yes I am. I'm updating the record